# Delete/Demolish an Outpost: Do you get the building costs back?

Tags: starfield

If we don't need an Outpost anymore, we can delete/demolish it.

Do we get the building costs back completely? Or just part of them? Or do we loose all the material invested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✅ Yes, you get all building costs back in full, when you remove an outpost.

✅ All material in storage containers and such are also returned.

ℹ Note: If your ship is in range, these resources and items will probably go to storage there, not your personal inventory. Quite possibly overloading it. Which is fine if it does— your ship will still fly and everything. You just won't be able to add more stuff to your overloaded ship until you clear it out.

Comment: Even if your personal inventory has enough free space to get back the material from the removed outpost, this resources will go to the inventory in your ship (landed some hundreds meter away.) This may give the false impression at first sight that we do not get the resources back.